# Python, LXML ElementTree not making elementtree out of STYLE element

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to get elements from an XML. Seems to be working fine for the entire document except when I hit anything in the STYLE element. Then lxml doesn't build the tree. Returns to normal function once past the element. I was thinking it might have been a reserved element name, but I cannot find anything confirming this. Maybe I'm missing something blatantly obvious...

```
import requests
import lxml.html

response = requests.get('http://www.beerxml.com/recipes.xml')

def depth(node):
    d = 0
    while node is not None:
        d += 1
        node = node.getparent()
    return d

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)

for recipe in tree:
  for child in recipe.iter():
    print(depth(child),child.tag, '\t\t\t',child.text)
```

Result:

```
5 style              
 <NAME>Witbier</NAME>
 <VERSION>1</VERSION>
 <CATEGORY>Belgian &amp; French Ale</CATEGORY>
 <CATEGORY_NUMBER>1</CATEGORY_NUMBER>
...
```

Expected result:

```
5 style              
6 name Witbier
6 version 1
6 category Belgian &amp; French Ale
6 category_number 1
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `import lxml.etree` instead `import lxml.html`

And replace

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
```

with

```
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.content)
```